What is the distribution of the observed counts of the Chi-squared test?
I was reading this answer, trying to get some intuition for how Pearson's chi-squared test works:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2074074/1226290
Everything makes sense from this answer, except for the assumption that the observed counts $O_{i}$ are actually poisson distributed. Since it is part of the null hypothesis for Pearson's chi-squared test that  the count numbers are sampled from a multinomial distribution $\mathrm{Multinomial}(N; p_1, ..., p_n)$, shouldn't the distribution of the observed counts be binomial distributed? I know that the binomial distribution with $n \rightarrow \infty,\ p \rightarrow 0$ such that $np \rightarrow \lambda\ $ tends towards the poisson distribution, but I don't see why we could assume that in this case, since the Pearson's chi-squared test doesn't require $n$ to be large or $p$ to be small for each component of the multinomial distribution in the null hypothesis.
A user named "sdd" asked the exact same question in a comment on the answer, but it has not been answered yet.
Is the answer wrong in assuming $O_{i}$ to be poisson distributed, or am I missing something?
